# Finding next node in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following table (Date + CustNum is an unique index)

| RowId | Date | CustNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-Jan-2021 | 0001 |
| 2 | 1-Jan-2021 | 0002 |
| 3 | 1-Jan-2021 | 0004 |
| 4 | 2-Jan-2021 | 0001 |
| 5 | 3-Jan-2021 | 0001 |
| 6 | 3-Jan-2021 | 0004 |
| 7 | 7-Jan-2021 | 0004 |

The table has ~500K records.

What is the best method to get the previous and next rowid of the CustNum?

| RowId | Date | CustNum | CustPrevRowId | CustNextRowId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-Jan-2021 | 0001 |  | 4 |
| 2 | 1-Jan-2021 | 0002 |  |  |
| 3 | 1-Jan-2021 | 0004 |  | 6 |
| 4 | 2-Jan-2021 | 0001 | 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 3-Jan-2021 | 0001 | 4 |  |
| 6 | 3-Jan-2021 | 0004 | 3 | 7 |
| 7 | 7-Jan-2021 | 0004 | 6 |  |

I've tried to use sub-query but I have faced a performance issue.

```sql
SELECT T1.*,
    (SELECT TOP 1 RowID FROM T T2 WHERE T2.CustNum = T1.CustNum AND T2.Date < T1.Date ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS CustPrevRowId,
    (SELECT TOP 1 RowID FROM T T2 WHERE T2.CustNum = T1.CustNum AND T2.Date > T1.Date ORDER BY DATE ) AS CustNextRowId
 FROM T T1
```

Comment: `LAG`/`LEAD` would be the "best" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed in the comments, you can use the two window functions:

- [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), retrieves the previous row in the same partition, given a specified order
- [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), does the same, but will get the following row instead

In this specific case, you want to:

- partition on "*CustNum*" (since you want last row for each customer number)
- order by the date field (so that it will attempt to get rowid with respect to last/next date)

```
SELECT *, LAG([RowId]) OVER(PARTITION BY [CustNum] ORDER BY [Date]) AS CustPrevRowId,
          LEAD([RowId]) OVER(PARTITION BY [CustNum] ORDER BY [Date]) AS CustNextRowId
FROM tab
ORDER BY RowId
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nUsexmX0).

**Note**: the last `ORDER BY RowId` clause is not necessary.

Comment: A follow up on the performance gains. It took me 3+ hrs using sub-queries, and now it's 1 min when using the windowed functions.